# Virtual Key Press in window C#

Tags: c#, postmessage

Hey, I am trying to type a message into notepad without having to have it as my focus window (Foreground Window).

This is what I have so far:

```
    const UInt32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    const int VK_F5 = 0x74;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);
    [STAThread]

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad");

            foreach (Process proc in processes)
                PostMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle, VK_TAB, VK_S, 0);

    }
```

But this does not type S into notepad. When I use VK_F5, it displays the date/time and when I use VK_F1 that displays the help window but it does not type s.

I have thought about using SendKey but that requires me to be targeting Notepad.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you supply a little context as to why you're doing this?

Comment: It's for a computer game, to log me in automatically

Comment: Just trying to get a handle on the necessity of Notepad. It's made for users to edit text. If they don't need to see the text, for example, you could write the keys to a text file and then open Notepad for the user when they need to see it.

Comment: Yeah that's a good idea, but like I just said, it's for a computer game, a notepad is just a simple way to try to get the program working

Comment: Lol, no doubt your going to use this to intercept a password.  I'll assume you share a computer.

Comment: No, I have no idea how I would do that. This is my own personal computer and like I said its to automatically start up a game and log me in. If I was doing that I would just create a global keyhook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if when you use VK_F5 it inserts the date, that means the send message procedure is working.

the problem is the destination of the message, you are sending the messages to the notepad window handle,

if you want keys to be written in the text area, you need to get the handle of the text area control of the notepad application and send the message to it

Comment: Ah I see, do you know how I would do this?

Comment: in these articles, they manage to get the handle of practically anything, take a dive into them

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/objectspy.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/winspy.aspx